# Add a class to parent element when clicked with Knockout.js

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have a div with a close button on it. The close button has a function fired via Knockout.js that I would like to add a class to the parent of this button, i.e. the encapsulating div. However, in my JS file (see below) the function firing is linked to an object in an array.

HTML

```
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.myFunc">
</div>
```

JS file

```
this.myFunc = function(e) {
//  this.addClass('boo'); does not work
}
```

I can fire a console.log off in this function, but can't seem to manipulate this element through standard jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Knockout way of doing it would be to add a css binding to the parent and then manipulate it within your function fired by click event:

```
<div data-bind="css: someClass">
    <button data-bind="click: myFunc">
</div>
```

And within your JS file:

```
this.someClass = ko.observable("");

this.myFunc = function(e) {
    this.someClass("boo");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

since you tagged jQuery, I assume you can use it, so:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('boo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, normally this would be fine, however I've just discovered that I am data-bound to an object in a database, so trying to manipulate in this way yields no results.

Answer (score -1):

This is my first answer on here but how about looking into jQuery's .parent() api? http://api.jquery.com/parent/

I'm not familiar with Knockout.js but perhaps something like this could work..

```
$('button').data('bind','click: $parent.myFunc').click(function(){

   $(this).parent().addClass('boo');   

 });
```

Comment: Haha Amin beat me too it! Glad I'm on the right track with my answer though!